# In extjs how to store selected radio buttons option

Tags: extjs4, radio-group

I am working in extjs+Yii. In extjs i am creating multiple choice question paper of 20 questions. These questions i am retriving from Yii framework. So in extjs i am having code as=
View=
Question.js

```
  Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.Question',   
     {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.question.QuestionView'
              ],
    id:'QuestionId',
    alias:'widget.question',
    title:'Question',
    height:180,
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'questionView',
        },

    ],//end of items square
    buttons:[
          {
              xtype:'button',
              fieldLabel:'Vote',
              name:'vote',
              formBind:true,
              text:'submit',
              action:'voteAction',
          }
    ]
         });
```

QuestionView.js

```
         Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.QuestionView',
             {
    extend:'Ext.view.View',
    id:'QuestionViewId',
    alias:'widget.questionView',
    store:'Question',
    config:
    {
        tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
            '<div id="main">'+
            '</br>'+
            '<b>Question :-</b> {question}</br>'+
            //'<p>-------------------------------------------</p>'+

            '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property                  within the data
                '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="opt" >&nbsp{option} </p>'+
            '</tpl></p>'+

            '</div>'+
            '</tpl>',
        itemSelector:'div.main',    
    }
```

});

So i am having view which is displaying question and its options as radio buttons. i am displaying 20 questions. At the end its having submit button. On the click of submit button,i want to display result. To calculate result i need to store user's selected options of all question in store of extjs in order to calculate result. So how to store all questions selected option in extjs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to place the form's radio button values into an ad-hoc Ext data store?

Comment: Thanx sir for reply...Actully,i want to save all 20 questions selected radio button option into store?